# Android: receiving null object from socket on server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have an server/client application that sends/receives updates about the users of the app (Members). Unfortunately, when the client on the Android device sends any getUpdate/sendUpdate Objects the server receives them as null.

I also have a PC version of the Android client that works perfectly fine. It has the same methods and everything.

Here is the client on the Android device:

```
public class AndroidApplication extends Application{
public static Log log;

private final static String TAG = "AndroidApplication";
public static final String SERVER = "192.168.1.136";

public static boolean chatCreated = false;
public static String chatText;
public static String username, level = MemberMessage.LEVEL4;
public static Context context;
public static int points = 0;

public static UpdateMember k;
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static void updateMember(){
    k = new UpdateMember(UpdateMember.SEND);
    k.start();
}
public static void getUpdateMember(){
    k = new UpdateMember(UpdateMember.GET);
    k.start();
}
public static void stopUpdateMember(){
    AndroidApplication.k = null;
}
static class UpdateMember extends Thread{
    static final int GET=0,SEND=1;

    boolean didConnectWork;
    boolean didUpdateWork;
    boolean didDisconnectWork;
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream sInput;
    ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
    boolean GetSend;

    public UpdateMember(int get_send){
        switch(get_send){
        case UpdateMember.GET:
            GetSend = true;
            break;
        case UpdateMember.SEND:
            GetSend = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    public void run(){
        if(GetSend){
            didConnectWork = connect();
            didUpdateWork = getUpdate();
            getInfoFromServer();
            didDisconnectWork = disconnect();
        }else{
            didConnectWork = connect();
            didUpdateWork = sendUpdate();
            try{
            getInfoFromServer();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG, "Something Bad");
            }
            didDisconnectWork = disconnect();
        }
        AndroidApplication.stopUpdateMember();
    }

    private boolean connect() {
        try{
            socket = new Socket(SERVER, 1520);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't connect to Member Server");
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Accepted at Membe Server!");

        /*
         * Create both data streams
         */
        try{
            sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't connect to Member Server");
            return false;
        }
        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(username);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't send username.");
            return false;
        }
        //everything worked
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to Member Server.");

        return true;
    }

    private boolean sendUpdate() {
        MemberMessage mh = new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.UPDATE, AndroidApplication.username,
                AndroidApplication.points, AndroidApplication.level);
        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(mh);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't update info");
            return false;
        }
        //everything worked!
        Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(mh.getType()));
        Log.i(TAG, "Update sent!");

        return true;
    }
    private boolean getUpdate(){
        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.UPDATE_REQUEST,
                    AndroidApplication.username, -1, null));
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't send GET message info");
            return false;
        }
        //itworked
        Log.i(TAG, "GET Update sent!");

        return true;
    }
    private void getInfoFromServer(){
        MemberMessage MM;
        /*
         * Will listen for both an update message and a Diconnect messafge form the
         * server.
         */
        boolean keep = true;
        while(keep){
            //************************************
            try{
                MM = (MemberMessage) sInput.readObject();
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't read message from server.");
                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't update info");
                break;
            }
            //the message to stop listening for updates
            switch(MM.getType()){
            case MemberMessage.DISCONECT:
                Log.i(TAG, "Received dsconnect message.");
                keep = false;
                break;
            case MemberMessage.UPDATE:
                /*
                 * Update our info in turn
                 */
                AndroidApplication.points = MM.getNumPoints();
                AndroidApplication.level = MM.getLevel();
                Log.i(TAG, "Updatted member with Points = " + AndroidApplication.points
                        + " and Level = " + AndroidApplication.level);
                try{
                    //tell the sever we recieved the info
                    sOutput.writeObject(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.RECIEVED, null, -1, null));
                }catch(IOException e){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't send received message");
                    keep = false;
                }
                break;
            }
            //*****************************************     
        }

    }

    private boolean disconnect() {
        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.DISCONECT, null, -1, null));
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't disconnet");
        }
        // try to close the connection
        try {
            if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't close output");
            return false;
        }
        try {
            if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
            }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't close input");
            return false;
        }
        try {
            if(socket != null) socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't close socket");
            return false;
        }
        return true;    
    }
}
}
```

For the PC version:

```
public class UpdateTest {
public static final String SERVER = "192.168.1.136";

public static boolean chatCreated = false;
public static String chatText;
public static String username = "TESTER", level = MemberMessage.LEVEL1;
public static int points = 90;

public static UpdateMember k;

public static void updateMember(){
    k = new UpdateMember(UpdateMember.SEND);
    k.start();
}
public static void getUpdateMember(){
    k = new UpdateMember(UpdateMember.GET);
    k.start();
}
public static void stopUpdateMember(){
    UpdateTest.k = null;
}
static class UpdateMember extends Thread{
    static final int GET=0,SEND=1;

    boolean didConnectWork;
    boolean didUpdateWork;
    boolean didDisconnectWork;
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream sInput;
    ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
    boolean GetSend;

    public UpdateMember(int get_send){
        switch(get_send){
        case UpdateMember.GET:
            GetSend = true;
            break;
        case UpdateMember.SEND:
            GetSend = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    public void run(){
        if(GetSend){
            didConnectWork = connect();
            didUpdateWork = getUpdate();
            getInfoFromServer();
            didDisconnectWork = disconnect();
        }else{
            didConnectWork = connect();
            didUpdateWork = sendUpdate();
            getInfoFromServer();
            didDisconnectWork = disconnect();
        }
        UpdateTest.stopUpdateMember();
    }

    private boolean connect() {
        try{
            socket = new Socket(SERVER, 1520);
        }catch(Exception e){

            return false;
        }


        /*
         * Create both data streams
         */
        try{
            sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException e){

            return false;
        }
        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(username);
        }catch(IOException e){

            return false;
        }
        //everything worked

        return true;
    }

    private boolean sendUpdate() {
        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.UPDATE, UpdateTest.username,
                    UpdateTest.points, UpdateTest.level));
        }catch(IOException e){

            return false;
        }
        //everything worked!


        return true;
    }
    private boolean getUpdate(){
        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.UPDATE_REQUEST,
                    UpdateTest.username, -1, null));
        }catch(IOException e){

            return false;
        }
        //itworked

        return true;
    }
    private void getInfoFromServer(){
        MemberMessage MM;
        /*
         * Will listen for both an update message and a Diconnect messafge form the
         * server.
         */
        boolean keep = true;
        while(keep){
            //************************************
            try{
                MM = (MemberMessage) sInput.readObject();
            }catch(IOException e){

                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                break;
            }
            //the message to stop listening for updates
            switch(MM.getType()){
            case MemberMessage.DISCONECT:
                keep = false;
                break;
            case MemberMessage.UPDATE:
                /*
                 * Update our info in turn
                 */
                UpdateTest.points = MM.getNumPoints();
                UpdateTest.level = MM.getLevel();

                try{
                    //tell the sever we received the info
                    sOutput.writeObject(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.RECIEVED, null, -1, null));
                }catch(IOException e){

                    keep = false;
                }
                break;
            }
            //*****************************************     
        }

    }

    private boolean disconnect() {
        System.out.println("Disconectin...");
        System.out.println(UpdateTest.username);

        System.out.println(UpdateTest.points);

        System.out.println(UpdateTest.level);

        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.DISCONECT, null, -1, null));
        }catch(IOException e){

        }
        // try to close the connection
        try {
            if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

            return false;
        }
        try {
            if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
            }
        catch(Exception e) {

            return false;
        }
        try {
            if(socket != null) socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;    
    }
}
public static void main(String... args){
    updateMember();
    getUpdateMember();
}
}
```

And now for the server:

```
public class MemberServer {
// a unique ID for each connection
private static int uniqueId;
//ArrayList of connected members
private static ArrayList<Member> ml;
//Arraylist of the Created user profiles
private static ArrayList<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();
//the port to be run on
static private final int PORT = 1520;
//will keep the server running
static private boolean keepGoing;

public MemberServer(){
    ml = new ArrayList<Member>();
    readUserList();
}
private void readUserList() {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try{
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/steven/Documents/Android/MemberServerTest/Users.txt"));
        String str = in.readLine();
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            members.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void begin(){
    keepGoing = true;
    /*
     * Create a socket server and wait for connections
     */
    try{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1520);

        //loop to wait for connections
        while(keepGoing){
            //message to say that we are waiting
            display("Server is waiting for Members on port " + PORT + ".");

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();// acctep connection
            //if asked to stop
            if(!keepGoing){
                break;
            }
            Member m = new Member(socket);
            ml.add(m);
            m.start();
        }
        try{
            serverSocket.close();
            for(int i = 0; i < ml.size(); ++i){
                Member mb = ml.get(i);
                try{
                    mb.sInput.close();
                    mb.sOutput.close();
                    mb.socket.close();
                    mb.createUserData(mb.username);
                }catch(IOException ioE){}
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
        Writer o = null;
        o = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("/home/steven/Documents/Android/MemberServerTest/Users.txt" ), "utf-8"));
        o.write("\n");
        for(Member k:ml){
            o.write(k.username + ",");
        }
        o.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected static void stop(){
    System.out.println("Now Stoping Server...");
    keepGoing = false;
    try{
        new Socket("localhost", PORT);
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
private void display(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
synchronized static void remove(int id){
    for(Member mn: ml){
        if(mn.id == id){
            ml.remove(mn);
            return;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String... args){
    MemberServer ms = new MemberServer();
    ms.begin();
}

class Member extends Thread{
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream sInput;
    ObjectOutputStream sOutput;

    public ArrayList<String> properties = new ArrayList<String>();
    public  int id;
    public  String username,level = MemberMessage.LEVEL4;
    public  int numPoints = 0, numUpvotes = 0;
    public  MemberMessage memMes;

    Member(Socket socket){
        boolean exists = false;
        id = ++uniqueId;
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println("Thread trying to create Object Input/Output Streams");
        try{
            //create output first
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //read the username
            username = (String) sInput.readObject();
        }catch(IOException e){} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(String str:members){
            if(str.equals(username)){
                loadUserData();
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        if(!exists){
            createUserData(username);
        }
    }
    private void createUserData(String username) {
        Writer out = null;
        try{
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("/home/steven/Documents/Android/MemberServerTest/" + username + ".txt" ), "utf-8"));
            out.write("\nUsername:" + username + ";Points:" + numPoints + ";Level:" + level + ";");
            System.out.println("Member data wittem for " + username);
        }catch(IOException e){}
        finally{
            try{
                out.close();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    private void loadUserData() {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/steven/Documents/Android/MemberSeverTest/" + username +".txt"));
            String str;
            str = in.readLine();
            while(( str = in.readLine()) != null){
                properties.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(";")));
            }
            in.close();
        }catch(IOException e){}
        finally{
            try{
                in.close();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        for(String i:properties){
            String[] me = i.split(":");
            if(me[0].equals("Username")){
                username = me[1];
            }else if(me[0].equals("Points")){
                numPoints = Integer.parseInt(me[1]);
            }else if(me[0].equals("Level")){
                level = me[1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Member data loaded for " + username);
    }
    public void run(){
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        while(keepGoing){
            try{
                memMes = (MemberMessage) sInput.readObject();
                if(memMes != null){
                    memMes = new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.UPDATE, this.username, this.numPoints, this.level);
                }else{
                    switch(memMes.getType()){
                    case MemberMessage.UPDATE:
                        System.out.println("Update message received from " + username);
                        this.username = memMes.getUsername();
                        this.numPoints = memMes.getNumPoints();
                        this.level = memMes.getLevel();
                        writeToMember(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.UPDATE, this.username, this.numPoints, this.level));
                        break;
                    case MemberMessage.RECIEVED:
                        System.out.println("Received message recieved from " + username);
                        writeToMember(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.DISCONECT, null, -1, null));
                        break;
                    case MemberMessage.DISCONECT:
                            System.out.println("Disconnecting from " + username + "...");
                            keepGoing = false;
                            break;
                    case MemberMessage.UPDATE_REQUEST:
                        display("GET request from " + username);
                        writeToMember(new MemberMessage(MemberMessage.UPDATE, this.username, this.numPoints, this.level));
                        break;
                    case 100:
                        System.out.println(memMes.getLevel());
                        MemberServer.stop();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException e){keepGoing = false; display("IOException");}
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e){keepGoing = false;}
            catch(NullPointerException e){
                keepGoing = false;
                display("NullPointerException");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        remove(id);
        close();
    }
    private void writeToMember(MemberMessage j){
        try{
            sOutput.writeObject(j);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error writing to " + username);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // try to close everything
    private void close() {
        createUserData(username);
        // try to close the connection
        try {
            if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
        try {
            if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {};
        try {
            if(socket != null) socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
}
```

Now, the issue I see is when the actual sendUpdate() method where the sOutput.wirteObject(mh) is called. At the server side this sent object is received as null. The way the server connects is that it accepts a socket connection, creates a Member Object to handle the IO, and then listens for any incomming MemberMessage Objects. The problem occurs when it receives the MemberMessage; however, its value is null.

Any ideas??
Thanks for any help beforehand!

Also, here is the MemberMessage class:

```
/**
 * This class will define the updates to the different properties of a Member object.
 * Properties include: usename, #points, and level. 
 *
 *
 */
public class MemberMessage implements Serializable{
protected static final long serialVersionUID = 110L;
public static final int UPDATE = 0, DISCONECT = 1, RECIEVED = 2, UPDATE_REQUEST = 3;
public static final String LEVEL1 = "I'm an expert and I want to help"
        ,LEVEL2 = "I'm doind okay and I don't need help - but I'm not confident enough to help others."
        ,LEVEL3 = "I need help"
        ,LEVEL4 = "I need a tutor because I just can't get the hang of this subject.";
private String username, level;
private int numPoints;
private int type;
public MemberMessage(int type, String username, int numPoints, String level){
    this.type = type;
    this.username = username;
    this.numPoints = numPoints;
    this.level = level;
}
public String getUsername(){
    return this.username;
}
public int getNumPoints(){
    return this.numPoints;
}
public String getLevel(){
    return this.level;
}
public int getType(){
    return this.type;
}
}
```

Comment: ObjectInputStream,read() only returns null if you sent a null with ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(). You must be ignoring an exception. Your exception handling is certainly very poorly structured. Don't write code after a catch block. Put it inside the try block.

Comment: See, the exact exception occurs at the `switch(memMes.getType())` line in the MemberServer$Member.run() method. When debugging in Eclipse, this throws a NullPointerException because `memMes = null`. Now, as you said, this can't happen unless the client sends a `null`. Why then, am I receiving a null value when I am not sending one? @EJP

Comment: I've answered that. Look again. You got an IOException shortly before and you ignored it and kept going, due to your poorly structured exception handling. Possibly an EOFException.

Comment: The Exception handling? That in itself is easy enough to fix; however, the fact of the matter is that the Exception should not be thrown in the first place, for the PC version runs without Exceptions. @EJP Also, it's a NullPointerException.

Comment: Look. You got an IOException which you ignored and continued as though you didn't get it. The IOException may have been an EOFException. If you got that you should have closed the socket and bailed out. If got any other IOException, ditto. Print the stack trace and you will find out. If you didn't write code like this you wouldn't get problems like this. It's no good just arguing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subsequent edit has obscured the fact, and indeed made your post entirely pointless, but you got an `IOException` calling `readObject()` and then continued as though you didn't get it, so the variable you read into was still null. Don't write code like this. The code that depends on the readObject() call succeeding should have been inside the try block along with the call.

And when you get an `IOException`, especially an `EOFException`, you should close the socket and exit the reading loop. Immediately. Not as at present.

Comment: First of all, thanks for all your time. I really do appreciate it even if it doesn't seem so. I definetly will look into the exception stuff though. But this is what i'm thinking: since the server works fine with the PC version I believe that the problem is with the Android portion. Any suggestions???